# Keras Average Layer with Masking

Tags: keras, merge, average, masking

The Average layer that comes with Keras already has support for masking, however, looking at the source code of Average Layer, it is not clear to me how and if the masking is applied.

I have a list of inputs, each with its own masking (coming from an embedding layer, for example). The average layer I want should take the average of those inputs that have not been masked. In other words, if an input is masked, it should not have any say in the calculated mean. If all the inputs are masked, then the output is masked and passed along to the next layers.

A related question is, the Average Layer that comes with the library only supports merge functions of a list of inputs. Is there library support for merging a tensor along a particular dimension? Is it possible to slice a tensor into a list of inputs to feed into the average layer? If not, how to take the average of tensor along some dimension in presence of masking?

I am inclining towards writing a custom average layer that computes the masks and consume the masks in calculating the output, but from the documentation, it is not clear how to do so?

Any pointers or code samples is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of the Average layer, it actually subclass from the "_Merge" layer, since Average layer doesn't overwrite the "compute_mask" function, so it will inherit the "compute_mask" function of "_Merge" layer, which is as follows:

```
  def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    if mask is None:
      return None
    if not isinstance(mask, list):
      raise ValueError('`mask` should be a list.')
    if not isinstance(inputs, list):
      raise ValueError('`inputs` should be a list.')
    if len(mask) != len(inputs):
      raise ValueError('The lists `inputs` and `mask` '
                       'should have the same length.')
    if all(m is None for m in mask):
      return None
    masks = [array_ops.expand_dims(m, axis=0) for m in mask if m is not None]
    return K.all(K.concatenate(masks, axis=0), axis=0, keepdims=False)
```

The last 4 lines say that: if all the input masks are None, then return None. Otherwise the output mask is first concatenating all the masks that are not None, then do a "all" operation, which means the resulted mask is masked (False) if one of the input_mask is masked (False), and the resulted mask is True (not masked) only if all the input_masks are not masked (True).